# Error while using facebook app invite for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am having an android application where I need to invite facebook friends. I use the below code

```
WebDialog requestsDialog = (
                new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(FacebookLogin.this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                    .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                            if (error != null) {
                                if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Request cancelled", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Network Error", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                                if (requestId != null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Request sent",  
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(FacebookLogin.this.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Request cancelled", 
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }   
                        }

                    })
                    .build();
            requestsDialog.show();
```

But it throws a syntax error "Incompatible conditional operand types FacebookException and FacebookOperationCanceledException" at line "if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)". 
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put **apprequests** to the `WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder`.

This is how I use it:

```
dialog = new WebDialog.Builder(activity, Session.getActiveSession(), "apprequests", params).
    setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error)
        {
            if (error != null && !(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException))
            {
                // error
            }
            else
            {
                // good
            }
            dialog = null;
        }
    }).build();

Window dialogWindow = dialog.getWindow();
dialogWindow.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

dialog.show();
```

---

Or, in addition, you can use this `SimpleFacebook` library that makes the life much easier by working with more simpler API than Facebook SDK 3.0. This library wraps the Facebook SDK 3.0:

- https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

And this is how to invite by using this library:

```
OnInviteListener onInviteListener = new SimpleFacebook.OnInviteListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onFail()
    {
        // insure that you are logged in before inviting
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to invite");
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Invitation was sent");
    }
};

mSimpleFacebook.invite(MainActivity.this, "I invite you to use this app", onInviteListener);
```

Hope, I could help you.

Comment: ,,,, can you tell me for which user id you are sending the request using the library mentioned above

Comment: The library updated and now it's `mSimpleFacebook.invite("I invite you to use this app", onInviteListener);` here you popup invite dialog with the list of all your friends.

Comment: Instead, you can set in this list part of the friends that you can invite. just see the example [here](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#suggested-friends)